# Secure way to pass image id to php file

Tags: php, html, security

Hello guys I'm working on a little picture upload site. I found a problem which can be exploitet I'll show you.

I do use a `foreach` to display every image so 1 image in html looks like this:

```
<a href="edit.php?id=ID_OF_PIC"><img src="IMG_PATH"></a>
```

The things written in caps are just examples but there are working values. In `edit.php` the `id` is used to update the pictures name. But if I'm a sneaky smart hacker I can change the `id` in the `href` and like this I can change another post. So how/where can I save/hide the `id` so that nobody can change it?

Comment: A `a` tag will not send post data, you have to use a form with `method=post`  and to `nobody can change it?` not possilbe a client-browser can manipulate **everthing**. Go and open F12 in the browser, there you can change live everthing, also javascript code, like you want.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I dont mean `post data` with post I mean 1 entry. No actually it is passed as `GET`.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Changed it for better understanding.

Comment: If you really want only allow an given id, then make it with a form and an unique token, an server side then check if the token and the id are still like that, that you have previsuly send to the browser via the form.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Can you provide me a link to something like that? I dont know what I should search.

Comment: How do you want to restrict it then? Who should be able to edit it? Its' not a "sneaky smart hacker" if you can edit another name, if you can do that anyway by just clicking the *right* link?

Comment: @Qirel Thats my Problem I search a way where I dont have to use a link.

Comment: Yes, but like I said, how do you want to restrict it? If everyone can edit any image anyways, it doesn't really matter if they can change the ID in the link; it would be equivalent to just click the link of the ID they changed to instead. If some users can just see/edit some, but not all pictures, then use that same validation you use showing them, when checking if they can edit the name or not.

Comment: @Qirel Everybody has his own album with pictures. They can just see their own albums. If they click on the album every pic in the album is shown. So if they change the `id` in their own album they can change a pic of another user.

Comment: This is likely one symptom of a poorly designed / missing user authentication and authorisation system. Without knowledge of that part of your app its not possible to answer. This is a multi-user app correct?

Comment: @WasteD Well, then the solution is simple: **Verify** in your `edit.php` that the user actually has access to the given ID. How you verify it depends on how your application is built.

Comment: @Qirel wow didn't think of that. This is really easy xD Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Qirel found a simple solution. Actually ist not very hard to do this. In my example I just have to check if the user who edits the image is the owner of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Solution: Use a form foreach image. Like:

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" value="ID_OF_PIC" name="id">
   <input type="hidden" value="TOKEN" name="tokenID_OF_PIC">
   <img src="IMG_PATH"><input type="submit" value="edit">
<form>
```

Before sending the form, create the TOKEN and save it in the session in relevance to the id.

`$_SESSION['tokens'][ID_OF_PIC]='TOKEN_FOR_ID_OF_PIC';`

A TOKEN should be a unique string for each image id.

When the form is posted , you got the id and the token. 
You know can check if the ID and the TOKEN are valid.

`if($_SESSION['tokens'][ID_OF_PIC]==$_POST['tokenID_OF_PIC']){}`

So this allowes user only edit pic that was sent by the server via the form with the right token.

But this does not prevent user to open a pic normal in the browser to view it, when the IMG_PATH also have the ID in it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort i'll mark your answer as correct but @Qirel gave me an easier solution so ill use this one. Thank you!

Comment: @WasteD if you have a better solution, post it as an answer, and accept it. For sure upvote other answers you feel useful, but dont just accept one to be nice, it does not help other site users at all

Comment: @Steve Actually Qirel should post the solution.

Comment: @WasteD No problem, take always the best solution.